# javascript returning true or false from a forEach loop

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get the function `loop()` to `return true` or `return false` after it's done checking if values in one array are present in another array. I'm stuck with where the return statements have to go since I'm new to javascript.

```
aa = ["one", "two", "three", 'four'];
ab = ["one", "two", "three"];
loop = function() {
  aa.forEach(function(i) {
    if(!ab.includes(i)) { 
      console.log (i + ' does not exists in ab') 
      // return false
    } else {
      console.log (i + ' exists in ab') 
    }
  });
}

console.log(loop()) // should return false since 'four' is not included in ab
```

Right now `loop()` returns `undefined`. How does this have to be done to make `loop()` return true or false?

Comment: Use `.some` instead: `aa.some(num => ab.includes(num))`

Comment: Ok. But when I do loop() how do I get it to return true or false?

Comment: By returning the `.some`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`forEach` does not return any value. Also function `loop` is not returning any value.

You can just iterate the array and use `some` to check that value is present in the other array

```js
const aa = ["one", "two", "three", 'four'];
const ab = ["one", "two", "three"];
aa.forEach((item) => {
  const isPresent = ab.some(elem => elem === item)
  console.log(isPresent)
})
```

Comment: I guess the complexity of this is O(n^2)?

Comment: `aa.some(item => ab.includes(item))`